# Generate test data from mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this model in nodejs app

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ServiceSchema = new Schema({
    Taxy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Taxy',
        required: 'Taxy cannot be blank'
    },
    User: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: 'User cannot be blank'
    },
    Servicio: String,
    Minutos: Number,
    Costo: Number, 
    Desc: String,
    From: String, 
    To: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

mongoose.model('Service', ServiceSchema);
```

I have surfed for a couple of days and I have not found a framework to generate random data from a model service, something like

```
var Service = require('mongoose').model('Admin').schema;
var jsondata = generateRandomeFromModel(Service)
```

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mongoose-fakery` module to generate `test` data

**Example:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
In your tests or fixture files:

var fakery = require('mongoose-fakery');

fakery.fake('user', mongoose.model('User'), {
    name: 'john',
    surname: 'doe'
});
```

You can go with complete reference [here](https://github.com/alexmic/mongoose-fakery)

Comment: I want auto generate test, that also the framework puts random data in the fields

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package called [Faker](https://fakerjs.dev/guide/#overview) that makes it easier.

```
npm install @faker-js/faker --save-dev
```

get relational data by [$sample (aggregation)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#definition)

```
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getFakeData = async () => {
    const taxy=await Model.Taxy.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]); //Randomly select document from `Taxy` Model 
    const user=await Model.User.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]);
    return ({
        Taxy: taxy.length && taxy[0]._id,
        User: user.length && user[0]._id,
        Servicio: faker.commerce.productAdjective(),
        Minutos: faker.datatype.number(),
        Costo: faker.datatype.number(),
        Desc: String,
        From: faker.name.findName(),
        To: faker.name.findName(),
        created: Date.now().toString()
    });
}

const fakeJsonData = await getFakeData();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution it was created 2 years ago. I tested it too it is working.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-dummy