# Create sample documents against mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema for documents for one collection of `mongodb`.

I want to randomly create 100 documents that complies with the schema i have defined.

I have searched over internet but could not find a suitable library.

Can you name or give links of a few tool or library for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624565/generate-test-data-from-mongoose-model